# Where is WinMain() in Win32 API implemented?

Tags: windows, winapi, winmain

Was just curious to know where the `WinMain()` method in the `Win32 API` is implemented. 
I know that `WinMain()` is declared in `WinBase.h`, but when the application runs, where does it refer to for `WinMain()` function's body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [WinMain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-winmain) explains, what it is:

> The **user-provided** entry point for a graphical Windows-based application.

It is declared in the SDK, but the program author is required to implement it.

When a new process is created, the OS calls into the executable image's exported entry point. By default, this is the C Runtime's (CRT) entry point ([WinMainCRTStartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol)), that prepares the execution environment prior to transferring control to the user-provided entry point `WinMain`. This is the first user-authored code that executes.

---

You can find more information on what is going on when when launching an executable on Windows at [WinMain is just the conventional name for the Win32 process entry point](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110525-00/?p=10573).

There's also a CppCon 2018 talk by [Matt Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) titled [The Bits Between the Bits: How We Get to main()](https://youtu.be/dOfucXtyEsU), that explains at length what's happening before the first line of user-authored code is executed. It is specific to Linux, but the principles apply to Windows as well.

Comment: "*This is the first user-authored code that executes*" - it should be noted that it is possible to write user code that runs *before* `WinMain()`/`main()` is called. For instance, in C++, using constructors of global objects. Or `#pragma startup` callback functions.

Comment: @rem: That has already been noted in the referenced article by Raymond Chen (*"For example, the C++ language startup code will run global constructors
before calling into `WinMain`"*).

Answer (score 3):

It's up to the program writer to implement it. Similarly to the requirement to implement main() in non-Windows environment.